# laravel : get properti from function in same class and parsing to view

Tags: laravel

in laravel i have function that return json format, in other function i try to get those function and parsing the json value into view

if i using return $this->functionName it is able to call function but how to parsing to view

```php
public function province()
{
    //open model
    $tracking = new Tracking;
    //call provinsi
    $url = "https://api.rajaongkir.com/starter/province";
    $province = $tracking->serverApi($url);
    $provinceJson = json_decode($province,true);
    $provinceJson =  $provinceJson["rajaongkir"]["results"];
    return $provinceJson;
    //return view('tracking/index',['province'=>$provinceJson]);          
}
```

and this is how i call the function and parsing to view

```php
public function loadProvince()
{
    return $this->province();
    return view('tracking/index',['province'=>$provinceJson]);
}
```

Comment: change `return $this->province();` to `$provinceJson = $this->province();`

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
public function loadProvince(){
        $provinceJson = $this->province();
        return view('tracking/index',['province'=>$provinceJson]);
    }
```

OR

```
public function loadProvince(){
            return view('tracking/index',['province'=>$this->province()]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

change the function to like this

```
public function loadProvince(){
    $provinceJson = $this->province();
    return view('tracking/index', ['province' => $provinceJson]);
}

OR
public function loadProvince(){
    $provinceJson = $this->province();
    return view('tracking/index', compact('provinceJson'));
}
```

Comment: Great but same as mine,